# Incorrect IF formula : expected 3, received 4

Tags: formula, formula-field, parameters, if

I need to add some lines into a formula and I started it but I'm stopped with the following issue :  Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 4. I saw there's another post that have quite the same name/issue but it didn't helped me.

My formula is at the end of this message. I don't succeed in finding where the issue is (it says expected 3 and received 4, but where ?). I checked the number of parentheses and the fact that each IF has 3 elements, maybe I missed something here (or elsewhere I didn't thought about)...
Could someone please take a look at it to help me ?

```
IF(Premiere_adhesion_cette_annee__c, 
    $Label.ACC_FIDELITE_NOUVEAU,
    IF(Adherent_exercice_courant__c,  
        IF(Adherent_exercice_precedent__c, 
            $Label.ACC_FIDELITE_FIDELE, 
            $Label.ACC_FIDELITE_REACTIVE 
        ),
        IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Date_de_premiere_adhesion__c)),
            IF(Demissionnaire_exercice_courant__c,                
                $Label.ACC_FIDELITE_DEMISSIONNAIRE,
                IF(adherent_exercice_precedent__c,      
                    $Label.ACC_FIDELITE_ENATTENTE,
                    $Label.ACC_FIDELITE_A_RELANCER
                )
            ),
            $Label.ACC_FIDELITE_PROSPECT
        )
    ),
    $Label.ACC_FIDELITE_PROSPECT
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Formatting it like it were code helps, so thanks for that!

If you remove the contents of the second `IF()`, just to help visualize things, you'll see that your outermost `IF()` looks like this:

```
IF(
    Premiere_adhesion_cette_annee__c, /* parameter 1 */
    $Label.ACC_FIDELITE_NOUVEAU,      /* parameter 2 */
    IF(
     ...                              /* parameter 3 */
    ),
    $Label.ACC_FIDELITE_PROSPECT      /* parameter 4 */
)
```

So your 4 parameter `IF()` is the outermost one